# Fantasy horror choose your own adventure book series involving a character called the Dark One who assumes the form of a squid

Tags: story-identification, books, horror, choose-your-own-adventure

This book series is of the "Choose your own adventure" genre. As far as I remember, it was of the fantasy horror genre. The ones I've read had plenty of either bad ending or "you die" paths. One part I remember is the main character being in a library and having the choice to insert one of a few different-colored orbs into the eye socket of a gargoyle statue. Another part that I remember involves a character simply called the Dark One. In one of the bad ending paths, the Dark One assumes the form of a squid-like creature that beats the characters to...something important by swimming towards it.

I don't remember anything about the time period it was set in, but probably not Victorian era. Maybe 20th century at the earliest? I remember the cover had the words "***Pick your path***" written somewhere, which is how it captured my attention in the first place

Comment: I can't find an exact match, but [Castle of Lost Souls](https://gamebooks.org/Item/42/Show) may have some elements in common. It was originally serialised in White Dwarf magazine. In the fourth and final segment (WD issue 55), you meet "Vimbol Greengosh" in a "vast, vaulted library with books and pamphlets lining every inch of the walls". He tells you that you must throw a teardrop into the Big Bad's eye to kill him. The teardrop is in a glass phial, though, not an orb. And the final encounter happens after you've left the library.

Comment: (I don't know if/how any of this differs in the book version.)

Comment: Another partial match is *Eye of the Dragon*, a solo adventure in Ian Livingstone's [Dicing with Dragons](https://archive.org/details/dicingwithdragon00ianl). In this, you journey into a labyrinth, seeking a golden statue of a dragon. You need to have two emeralds in your possession at this point, and you must insert them both into the statue's eye sockets to win the game and escape the dungeon.

Comment: An even more partial match... at the very end of [Deathtrap Dungeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathtrap_Dungeon), you need to have found three differently coloured gemstones (sapphire, emerald and diamond), and to place them into sockets on a door in the correct order. There's also an idol with two emeralds for eyes, and I think you need to remove the first of these - it's the emerald mentioned above.

Comment: OP - which year do you remember reading/playing these gamebooks? Do you remember what sort of fantasy horror setting this might have been - Call of Cthulhu perhaps, gothic horror like Frankenstein or Dracula, maybe D&D with horror tropes tacked on?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I would say that I read this book sometime after 2010. I didn't finish it, but I would say the horror is closer to that of Cthulhu or Dracula, rather than DnD. I read the book in physical form.

Comment: OK. Can you tell us some more about the time period it appeared to be set in? 1920s like a lot of Cthulhu games? Victorian era like Dracula? A Middle-Ages inspired fantasy setting?

Comment: Also, do you remember anything about the publisher, author, or publication date? And any information you can give as to the cover art would help as well.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I don't remember anything about the time period it was set in, but probably not Victorian era. Maybe 20th century at the earliest? I remember the cover had the words "Pick your path" written somewhere, which is how it captured my attention in the first place.

Comment: The second suggestion made by @Valorum above - gamebooks.org/Item/2163/Show - DOES have "Pick Your Path" on both the front and back covers! So that, or a book from the same series, looks likely. Though with that one, I think the orbs for the gargoyle's eye sockets may only have been in one colour (black).

Comment: I've searched the books from that series as best I can on Google Books. [Eye Spy Aliens](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Eye_Spy_Aliens/h5tRmgGxUQUC) has aliens with tentacles in it. Several books in the series involve libraries. [Revenge of the Gargoyle](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Revenge_of_the_Gargoyle/HQnLGUh8KU4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=inauthor:%22Tracey+West%22+%22pick+Your+Path%22+sebastian&dq=inauthor:%22Tracey+West%22+%22pick+Your+Path%22+sebastian&printsec=frontcover) looks like it has marbles in several colors, although only the black ones are eyes for the gargoyle.

Comment: After more Google Books searching in Revenge of the Gargoyle, there may be something with a beak that had gold marbles for eyes. And three marbles (one white and one silver) are arranged into a specific pattern in another scene. I've searched for "tentacle" and Google Books says the word does occur in that book, but won't show me the text where it does. Likewise "swim" and "swam", plus (supposedly) twenty-five matches for "Dark One" (that it still won't show me). I don't know why Google Books has stopped showing me snippets, maybe you'll have more luck with it.

Comment: Anyway, I reckon @Valorum was right, and it is Revenge of the Gargoyle. Hopefully Google Books will be a bit more helpful when searching inside that book tomorrow.

Comment: Taking your advice and doing a Google Books search for "Revenge of the Gargoyle" "sockets", I can find the bit about the one with gold eyes. I don't have an imgur account and I need to go offline soon, so unfortunately I can't post the evidence tonight.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - Probably worth tidying up all these comments now that we have an answer

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[Revenge of the Gargoyle](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/299608.Revenge_of_the_Gargoyle)* by Tracey West?

> The unusual black marble that Tania Robbins buys for her grandfather in Sebastian Cream's Junk Shop is no ordinary marble-it is the missing eye of one very angry gargoyle! Now he's demanding it back and Tania doesn't know what to do. It's up to you to decide!
>
> [image]

This gamebook was part of the [Pick Your Path](https://www.goodreads.com/series/136095-scream-shop-pick-your-path) series of books and featured those words prominently on the cover. There's mention of a [tentacled monster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIzhv.png) and uses the term ['The Dark One'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeHpS.png) to describe the book's baddie.